# How to connect two computers (AWS Snowball & mini PC) together with ethernet only?

Tags: ethernet, lan, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect two computers (AWS Snowball device & mini PC). The snowball device only has an ethernet port and I have a standard cable and a crossover cable but when I connect with either, nothing works. I think my problem is that I need to manually set the network setting of the snowball device (it defaults to 0.0.0.0) but I'm not sure what to set it to. I could go buy a router/switch dedicated to bridge these two devices but I wanted as small a footprint as possible. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Because you are directly connecting the devices there is nothing to allocate IP addresses to them.  (Normally a router provides this via DHCP).  If you statically assign addresses to each device (in the same subnet) they will likely be able to communicate with each other. You could use the IP addresses 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2, specifying a netmask of 255.255.255.0 - this is one of a huge number of valid possibilities.

Comment: interesting... so if I just connect the two devices via normal cat5 (do I need a crossover cable), they will be able to see each other?

Comment: Normally, yes they can see each other.  If they are gigabit you can use a straight through cable as it will autonegotiate.  If they are 100 megabit or slower you likely need a crossover.